# List all registered Shopify webhooks

Tags: shopify, webhooks

I am trying to find all registered webhooks on shopify. I am handling a shopify app which is  developed by some other developers and they did not documented that when/where they have registered webhooks . For example , they might have registered a "update order"  webhook with PUT **https://example.com/update** but My back-end server have many put endpoints.
So I am not sure which update end point is registered with shopify that why I am trying to find all the registered webhooks.

I have gone through the docs https://shopify.dev/api/admin/rest/reference/events/event#order-events-2021-07

I also find in this youtube video that I can see only the hooks that is created by me. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FO2ch1wxfcQ&t=350s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply made a request to `/admin/api/api-version/webhooks.json` to get the list of all webhook registered into Shopify API.
Here is the link for more details: https://shopify.dev/api/admin/rest/reference/events/webhook